# How can I access values stored in a variable of type "Any"

Tags: swift, polymorphism, swift5

I can store a value in a variable of type `Any` quite easily, but I can't figure out how to access it.

Just plain trying to assign `a` to `i` gives me this error message:`error: cannot convert value of type 'Any' to specified type 'Int'`

And trying to cast it gives me this error message:
`error: protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`

```swift
let a: Any = 1

//this doesn't work
let i: Int = a

//this doesn't work
let i: Int = Int(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because Int doesn't have an initializer that accepts type Any. To make it work you need to tell compiler that a is actually an Int. You do this like this:

```
let a: Any = 1
let i: Int = a as! Int
```

Edit:
If you are not sure about type of a, you should use optional casting. There are many approaches.

```
let i1: Int? = a as? Int  // have Int? type
let i2: Int = a as? Int ?? 0  // if a is not Int, i2 will be defaulted to 0
guard let i3 = a as? Int else {
    // what happens otherwise
}
```

Comment: This will crash if `a` is not in fact an `Int`.  It's better to use `if let i = a as? Int { // use i }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it. It's just `a`.

But you can't do much beyond that. Aside from a handful of actually universal functions (`print`, `dump`, etc.), there's really not much that you can do with an `Any`.

There's a gradient of generality and usefulness. On one extreme is `Any`. It's nearly useless. It doesn't require anything of its conforming types. But as a result, it's incredibly general. Literally all types conform to it.

On the other extreme is a concrete type like `Int`. If you have a parameter that expects an `Int`, only one type of value is allowed: `Int`. But this specificity buys you utility. You know that this value supports being added, multiplied, converted to string, etc.

The only way to do anything useful with `Any` is to down-cast it with `as`/`as?`/`as!` into a more restricting (less general) type.